# How to arrange content into grid view dynamically?

Tags: html, css, django, jinja2

I want to arrange the following **Figure1** content into horizon grid view, here content coming into vertical so, how to arrange into horizontal grid view, like **Figure2**

**Figure1**:

[image]

**Figure2**:

[image]

**Here I only required the css class in div, Please tell the css class to arrange the grid into horizontal form.**

Jinja2 Templates

**_data_grid.html**
This template, takes rows(number of data, like in the following Figure2 we have 5 data), and columns(Image Name, Type, Status, public, protected, Formate, size, Action), All these info comes from the database and django framework.

```
{% load i18n %}
{% with table.needs_form_wrapper as needs_form_wrapper %}
    <div class="table_wrapper">
    {% if needs_form_wrapper %}<form action="{{ table.get_full_url }}" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}{% endif %}
        {% with columns=table.get_columns rows=table.get_rows %}   

            {% block grid %}
                <grid id="{{table.slugify_name}}">
                    <div>
                        {% block grid_caption %}

                            <h3 class='table_title'>{{ table }}</h3>
                            {{ table.render_table_actions }}

                        {% endblock grid_caption %}
                    </div>
                    </br>
                    </br>
                    </br>
                    </br>
                    {% block grid_body %}
                        <div>
                            {% for row in rows %}
                            {{ row.render }}
                            {% empty %}

                            {{ table.get_empty_message }}
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                    {% endblock grid_body %}
                </grid>
            {% endblock grid %}
        {% endwith %}
        {% if needs_form_wrapper %}</form>{% endif %}
    </div>
{% endwith %}
```

**_data_grid_cell.html**
This template is used to fill the content,

```
{% if cell.inline_edit_mod and cell.update_allowed %}

{% else %}

{% if cell.inline_edit_available and cell.update_allowed %}

{% else %}

        <ul>{{ cell.value }}</ul>
{% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to code the css your self [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) will be what you are looking for. But I will be easier and probably cleaner to use css frameworks like [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/), your code should look somthing like this, then you can add django template tags:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4"><!--block 1--></div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4"><!--block 2--></div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4"><!--block 3--></div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4"><!--block 4--></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Check ([Bootstrap Grid](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/)) for more details and explanation for the css classes.